# How to launch a chai test in node?

Tags: node.js, express, chai, chai-http

I have a node/typescript application. I'm trying to test routes with chai and chai-http. I can launch a file when I write an explicit name: `yarn test myroute.test.ts`, but `yarn test` at the root does nothing.

Also, the test is never performed. I only receive a `Done in 0.06s.` in my terminal. No "passed" or "failed".

Here is the test:

```js
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import { server } from "../index";

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const chaiApi = chai.request(server);
describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", async () => {
    const res = await chaiApi
      .get("/user/123")
      .set("Cookie", "_id=567;locale=en");
    chai.assert.equal(res.status, 200);
  });
});
```

the package.json script is: `"test": "test"`. I assume it's completely wrong, but chai doc says nothing about what to write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chai` is an assertion library, similar to Node's built-in `assert`. It does NOT contain a test runner. You need to use [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) to collect and run your declared test suites and test cases.

After adding the mocha test framework, you can declare `npm test` script like this:

```json
"test": "mocha --require ts-node/register --timeout 5000",
```

In order to run the TS test file, we need to specify `ts-node/register`. Use it like this:

```
yarn test myroute.test.ts
```